# Precisely describing the set of "the subgroup generated by S"

Tags: group-theory, logic, notation, definition, quantifiers

In group theory, one equivalent way to define the subgroup generated by the set $S$ is the following:

$$\big \langle S \big \rangle = \{s_{1}^{e_1}...s_n^{e_n}\mid n=1,2,...,; i=1,2,...,n; e_i=\pm1, s_i \in S \}$$

Obviously, this form of describing the set is rather imprecise. So, this is my attempt at writing it in a more "precise" fashion (I'll assume we know what a finite product of the elements of a group is):

$$ \big \langle S \big \rangle = \{x \mid (\exists n \in \mathbb{N})(\forall 1 \leq i \leq n)(\exists e_i \in \{1,-1\})(\exists s_i \in S)(x = {\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{n} s_{j}^{e_j}})\}$$

Is this version correct? I'm not sure if we are allowed to use subscripts as a bound variable within quantifiers, without defining exactly what a subscript is. If that is the case, I'd be thankful if you could recommend a precise definition for subscripts (and superscripts).

Comment: First version is more for the working mathematician. Keep in mind the case $n=0$ (empty product) which leads to the unit element.

Comment: It's impossible to decide whether your second is "more precise" until you specify exactly what language you are trying to use. This won't work in the FOL language of groups. As you say the difficulty lies in exactly what one may quantify. [BTW the first formula won't do, $n=1,\dots, n$ is meaningless; the second has a typo, missing $e_i$s.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you. I fixed the typos. 
I'm quite new to the concept of language and logic. Is working with the language of ZFC enough of a specification?

Comment: The correctness of your definition depends on what definition of ${\mathbb N}$ you are using. If your aim is to be precise then you need to define the symbolds used in your definition.

Comment: @HeleyrineBrookvinth With the risk of seeming very blunt, I will make the claim that never should the formulaic description featured in your first formula row be given as the definition of the subgroup generated by a given subset $S \subseteq G$, in the context of given group $(G, \cdot)$. The only acceptable *definition* is that the subgroup generated by $S$ is **the intersection of all subgroups of** $G$ **which include** $S$, or $\langle S \rangle=\displaystyle\bigcap_{S \subseteq H \leqslant G} H$ in formal language *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @HeleyrineBrookvinth *(cont.)* where there is of course an abbreviation (a rather standard one) implicit in the above notation. The formulaic descriptions you are referring to on your 2 formula rows are precisely this, *descriptions* or if you will *characterisations* of the form of a generic element in the subgroup generated by $S$, however it is not proper pedagogy to consider them as the definition of the discussed notion.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ, I'd say that *the* definition is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $S$, smallest in the set theoretic sense. Then your characterization is a (simple) theorem. This appears in several other contexts, eg topology and convex hulls. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator

Comment: @lhf I'd say we are referring to the same background constructions & concepts albeit with somewhat different formulations. I am well aware of closure operators (and closure systems, as I like to call them) and I agree that a very easy to convey description for the $\mathscr{K}$-substructure generated by $X \subseteq A$ is the smallest (with respect to inclusion) member of (the closure system) $\mathscr{K}$ (on $A$) that contains $X$. However, in terms of formal descriptions one must first consider the object $\displaystyle\bigcap_{X \subseteq K \in \mathscr{K}} K$ *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @lhf *(cont.)* before reaching the conclusion that the said minimum exists, so in a sense the above formulaic description would come prior to $\mathrm{min} \{K \in \mathscr{K} \mid X \subseteq K\}$. Within the confines of mere comments I didn't intend to even touch on this general framework of closure systems, which is why I proposed a formal description that can be easily understood without any reference to them (whereas the one involving the minimum with respect to inclusion would have required some background explanation).

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the original formula is (modulo one small issue mentioned below) precise. You seem to be conflating two different issues.

*Being precise* has to do with vagueness and the possibility of misinterpretation. I do not see any way how your definition can be misinterpreted.

*Being formal* has to do with whether your definition conforms to the precise specification of some formal language or another. Your definition, of course, does not, but so what?

Unless your intended audience is an automatic proof assistant which requires that its input be given in some formal language, this is not a problem. Assuming that the intended context is in a text made for human consumption, the second definition is not in any way an improvement on the first. In fact, it is worse than the first definition because it is more difficult to read. If you want to write mathematics well, focus on how easy it is for humans to understand your text, not on whether your text conforms to the definition of a formula of ZFC (or some other theory) given in a logic course.

The only point of actual *imprecision* in your definition is that if $S$ is empty, your definition outputs the empty set, but it should in fact output the trivial subgroup. The easiest way to fix this is not to mess with the formula itself, but to change the context slightly. You could say something like: the subgroup generated by a non-empty set $S$ is

$\langle S \rangle = \{ s_{1}^{e_{1}} \cdots s_{n}^{e_{n}} \mid s_{i} \in S \text{ and } e_{i} \in \{ +1, -1 \} \text{ for } 1 \leq i \leq n \text{ with } n \in \omega \}$.

Notice in particular that you are allowed to use normal English words inside set builder notation.

Comment: Thank you for this perspective. However, I'm ought to believe if rigour is only intended for automatic proof readers, it completely undermines any need for formality and formal logic. Why use axioms, when one can intuitively describe the meaning of set as a "collection of objects"? Well, because being too carefree might result in contradictory results and paradoxes in your foundation.

Comment: I know this problem is more probable to occur in our foundation, and not in a "high-level" area such as Group theory, but perhaps one can  think of it as a "thought experiment". A practice for formality, if you will.

Comment: "[I]f rigour is only intended for automatic proof readers, it completely undermines any need for formality and formal logic." Far from it. If you want to reason *about* first-order logic, then you need to have a precise definition of first-order logic. For example, to make a claim such as "the class of all connected graphs is not first-order definable" or "the Continuum Hypothesis is independent of ZFC" precise, one needs a precise definition of the language of first-order logic. Not so in your example. As a thought experiment it's fine, but I would advise against actually writing this way.

Comment: @HeleyrineBrookvinth Secondly, *rigour* is necessary. Writing your definitions in the language of first-order logic is not. These are two different things. I am not claiming that " rigour is only intended for automatic proof readers". What I am claiming is that your assertion that "this form of describing the set is rather imprecise" is not true. Ironically, failing to distinguish between questions of precision and questions of formality is itself an instance of imprecision.

Comment: English is not my first language, therefore my understanding of certain mathematical terms need translation, and "precision" was my translation of the concept of "formality". I think arguing about the semantics of the words is not useful here at all. After all, it is a trivial matter that a working mathematician understands the first "informal" description of the set. The word I used to describe my intent was just to get my point across. And also, since "precision" is not a mathematical term (unlike "formality"), one can independently assume different meanings, which may cause misunderstanding

Comment: Besides that, another issue is that formal languages, although unintuitive at first (like any foreign language) are a way of precision. They trim out intuition and unstated assumptions in a mathematical discussion. Though again, this instance was just an example of the question "how to formalize the notion of a bound subscript variable in a formal sentence".  That is why I believe a crucial part of rigor is using formal languages. As for a definition of First-Order logic, I imagined that it was universal, is it not?

Comment: As in a set of alphabets (function, constant, and relation symbols and also variables), L-terms, L-formulas etc. I would understand if your criticism was that I didn't specify **which** First-Order language I'm using, as in what are the axioms we are working with (which I assumed if I didn't specify, it would be assumed as ZFC), but I don't understand your criticism of "what is a First-Order language, at all?".
@Pilcrow

Comment: @HeleyrineBrookvinth "They trim out intuition and unstated assumptions in a mathematical discussion." What do you imagine the unstated assumptions in your supposedly imprecise definition to be? "I believe a crucial part of rigor is using formal languages." No, rigor is about making precise, water-tight logical arguments. You can make precise, water-tight logical arguments in English without having to formalize them. Indeed, that's how mathematicians write their papers.

Comment: @HeleyrineBrookvinth Let me also reiterate that in your focus on the issue of writing a formally correct sentence you missed the more important issue, which is that your definition is incorrect if $S$ is empty. So in reality, fussing about formality did *not* reveal the flaw in the definition.

Comment: And how does one exactly determine a factor for what is a "water-tight, logical argument", exactly? (Formal) language is created for the specific means of being the criteria for determining the truth of arguments. How "water-tight", they are, if you like.

In the foundational parts of mathematics, the mathematician formalizes what may seem to his working counterpart trivial and unnecessary in making precise arguments, and yet not having formalization in one's foundations is precisely why paradoxes like Russell's happen.

Comment: Also, I did not claim to have mastered formalization. My question was specifically asking for guidance in regards to **how** I can do it better than I have; I actually do appreciate you pointing that it doesn't consider the empty set. 

I understand my question is not "the correct question to ask, in the first place", or "fussing" over unimportant matters in your view, and I do appreciate your perspective (as I also mentioned in the beginning of this long thread); But I would be thankful if your aim was not merely to "correct" an opposing (even wrong) view, but understand it first.

Comment: @HeleyrineBrookvinth I wasn't trying to be antagonistic and I do understand your view. But the idea that to be precise one needs to use some sort of formal language is a common enough misconception that I felt the need to comment on it. My claim isn't that misunderstanding and imprecision *cannot occur* in natural language. Rather, my claim is that it *does not occur* in your definition, contrary to what you claim ("Obviously, this form of describing the set is rather imprecise."). You are welcome to argue against this, but this would require showing in what ways the definition is imprecise.

Comment: Concerning Russell's paradox, the idea that "not having formalization in one's foundations is precisely why paradoxes like Russell's happen" sounds *prima facie* plausible, but in actual fact what happened was precisely the opposite: the paradox was discovered by Russell in the *formal* system of Frege's Grundgesetze der Arithmetik. (More recently, other formal systems have been shown to fall victim to Russell-type paradoxes, such as Martin-Löf's original intuitionistic type theory, called System U by Girard.) In other words, formalization is no protection against Russell-type paradoxes.